# Flask module not found error when using flask run

Tags: python, flask

Everything would work if I were to run the command -

```
>>> python3 app.py
```

But when I run -

```
>>> flask run
```

I am met with the error

```
Error: While importing "application.app" ....
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
```

and I have the environment variable set to -

```
>>> export FLASK APP=app.py
```

My files look like as follows -

**app.py**

```
import lib.logger as logger
import api.my_api as my_api

def run():
    logger.init_logging()
    my_api.app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

**my_api.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def test():
    return 'success'
```

**folder structure**

```
application/
├── __init__.py
├── app.py
├── lib/
|   ├── __init__.py
│   └── logger.py
└── api/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── my_api.py
```

Comment: I have no problem running this code without setting the environment variable

Comment: @Paul not sure what I'm doing wrong then... doesn't seem to be working